# Not able to start the instance since instance object variable not being updated , boto3

Tags: python

I am trying to STOP and then START a list of instances, i need to check also if the instance is stopped or not and similarly for the start part.

The code looks like

```
client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name=region, )
response = client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
print "Stopping instance Now",response['StoppingInstances']

for instance in response['StoppingInstances']:
    while instance['CurrentState']['Name'] != "stopped":
        print "Inside the STOP while LOOP"
        if instance['CurrentState']['Name'] == "stopped":
           print "Now instance is Stopped!!!"
        else :
           print "Instance is still being Stopped"
```

This keeps on printing :

```
Inside the STOP while LOOP
Instance is still being Stopped
Inside the STOP while LOOP
Instance is still being Stopped
.
.
.
.
<to_infinity>
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very busy loop, you might want to add a `sleep` in there.
You aren't updating the status but just referring the same status each time, you need to get the up-to-date status. Given you are just stopping a single `instance_id` then you can do:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
response = ec2.Instance(instance_id).stop()

while ec2.Instance(instance_id).state['Name'] != "stopped":
    print "Instance is still being Stopped"
    time.sleep(5)
else:
    print "Now instance is Stopped!!!"
```

If you are waiting for a list of instances to stop then you can use:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
response = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids).stop()

while all(i.state['Name'] != 'stopped' for i in ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids)):
    print "Instances are still being Stopped"
    time.sleep(5)
else:
    print "All instances are Stopped!!!"
```

Comment: okay, i am actually passing a list of instance , and once these instances are stopped i need to actually start them as well , so if i just change the stop to `start()` will this suffice?

Comment: Yes you can start all the instances with `start()`

Comment: and i get this `AttributeError: 'ec2.Instance' object has no attribute 'status'`

Comment: Sorry was typing from memory `state` not `status`.